# JavaFX having trouble laying out controls on a high density screen?

Tags: java, javafx

I developed an application with JavaFX and one of my customers is using a laptop with a high density display: 3200x1800 for a 13.3 inch display. When my app starts, the layout is wrong, as in, the width and height of each control is twice what it should be and thus doesn't fit in the window. As soon as the window is resized, the controls are re-lay-out properly.

I tried to reproduce it on my own computer by using Windows scaling feature, but it didn't reproduce the same issue my customer is seeing. Also, I'm using Java 8u162, which is supposed to have scaling implemented properly.

Any ideas what's going on or how to reproduce it?

Comment: If you mean like https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46453780/javafx-how-i-can-bind-a-stage-with-screen-resolution ,you limited your controls/layout size ,did you tried with COMPUTED_SIZE ,Please ,can you take a screenshot of UI ?

Comment: Make sure that  your stage is showing according to screen resolution ,i mean did you use fix sizes for your stage or responsive sizes by using Toolkit ?