# How to make AnchorPane size responsive to the maximized screen view

Tags: java, javafx

I don't know what is the grey area and how to extend my `Anchorpane` to all over the screen
[Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/m5HqA.png)

the not unmaximized view is this [image2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/14QC3.png)

My Fxml is a bit messy with alot of an Anchorpanes but it was out of my hand.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<!-- <?import com.gluonhq.charm.glisten.control.TextField?> -->

<?import javafx.scene.control.Button?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.ComboBox?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.DatePicker?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.Label?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.TableColumn?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.TableView?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.TextField?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.AnchorPane?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.VBox?>
<?import javafx.scene.text.Font?>
<?import javafx.scene.text.Text?>

<VBox alignment="CENTER" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/19" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" fx:controller="com.maxxplusapi.controller.ActvityPlannerController">
   <children>
      <AnchorPane maxHeight="-Infinity" maxWidth="-Infinity" minHeight="-Infinity" minWidth="-Infinity">
         <children>
            <AnchorPane style="-fx-background-color: white;" AnchorPane.bottomAnchor="0.0" AnchorPane.leftAnchor="0.0" AnchorPane.rightAnchor="0.0" AnchorPane.topAnchor="0.0">
               <children>
                  <TextField fx:id="beginTime" layoutX="256.0" layoutY="189.0" prefHeight="26.0" prefWidth="172.0" promptText="Beginnzeit" style="-fx-border-color: black;" />
                  <TextField fx:id="endTime" layoutX="472.0" layoutY="189.0" prefHeight="26.0" prefWidth="172.0" promptText="Endzeit" style="-fx-border-color: black;" />
                  <TextField fx:id="reminderDesc" layoutX="255.0" layoutY="104.0" prefHeight="26.0" prefWidth="388.0" promptText="Erinnerungsnachricht" style="-fx-border-color: black;" />
                  <TextField fx:id="txtRemarks" layoutX="255.0" layoutY="145.0" prefHeight="26.0" prefWidth="388.0" promptText="Remarks" style="-fx-border-color: black;" />
                  <Button fx:id="saveButton" layoutX="309.0" layoutY="357.0" mnemonicParsing="false" onMouseClicked="#addData" prefHeight="25.0" prefWidth="92.0" style="-fx-border-color: black;" text="Speichern" />
                  <AnchorPane>
                     <children>
                        <AnchorPane layoutY="-8.0" prefHeight="43.0" prefWidth="925.0" style="-fx-background-color: #2e4b75;"/>
                     </children>
                  </AnchorPane>
                  <Label layoutX="446.0" layoutY="243.0" text="Intervall" />
                  <Label layoutX="252.0" layoutY="280.0" text="Projekt Bereich" />
                  <ComboBox fx:id="cycleComboBox" layoutX="494.0" layoutY="238.0" prefWidth="150.0" style="-fx-border-color: black;" />
                  <ComboBox fx:id="projectComboBox" layoutX="252.0" layoutY="304.0" prefHeight="27.0" prefWidth="388.0" style="-fx-border-color: black;" />
                  <Button fx:id="updateButton" layoutX="309.0" layoutY="357.0" mnemonicParsing="false" onMouseClicked="#Edit" prefHeight="25.0" prefWidth="92.0" text="Update" />
                  <Text layoutX="225.0" layoutY="85.0" strokeType="OUTSIDE" strokeWidth="0.0" text="Aktivitätsplaner " textAlignment="CENTER" wrappingWidth="452.7265625">
                     <font>
                        <Font name="System Bold" size="36.0" />
                     </font>
                  </Text>
                  <Button contentDisplay="CENTER" layoutX="404.0" layoutY="357.0" mnemonicParsing="false" onMouseClicked="#DeleteData" prefHeight="25.0" prefWidth="92.0" text="Delete" />
                  <TableView fx:id="tableViewBooking" layoutX="104.0" layoutY="403.0" onMouseClicked="#getSelected" prefHeight="238.0" prefWidth="694.0">
                    <columns>
                      <TableColumn fx:id="tableID" editable="false" prefWidth="76.800048828125" text="id" />
                      <TableColumn fx:id="tableColName" editable="false" prefWidth="104.79997253417969" text="Erinnerung" />
                       <TableColumn fx:id="tableColRemarks" editable="false" prefWidth="104.79997253417969" text="Remarks" />
                       <TableColumn fx:id="tableColProject" editable="false" prefWidth="104.79997253417969" text="Projekt" />
                      <TableColumn fx:id="tableColDate" editable="false" prefWidth="83.20001220703125" text="Begin Datum" />
                      <TableColumn fx:id="tableColHours" editable="false" prefWidth="66.39996337890625" text="Stunde" />  
                       <TableColumn fx:id="tableColType" editable="false" prefWidth="71.20001220703125" text="Intervall" />
                      <TableColumn fx:id="tableColSTime" editable="false" prefWidth="76.800048828125" text="Begin Zeit" />   
                      <TableColumn fx:id="tableColETime" editable="false" prefWidth="76.800048828125" text="End Zeit" />
                      
                      <!--<TableColumn fx:id="tableColProj" prefWidth="75.0" text="Projekt" /> -->
                    </columns>
                  </TableView>
                  <DatePicker fx:id="beginDate" layoutX="253.0" layoutY="239.0" prefHeight="26.0" prefWidth="172.0" promptText="Begindatum" />
                  <DatePicker fx:id="endDate" layoutX="441.0" layoutY="239.0" prefHeight="26.0" prefWidth="172.0" promptText="Enddatum" visible="false" />
                  <Button layoutX="500.0" layoutY="357.0" mnemonicParsing="false" onMouseClicked="#clearFields" prefHeight="25.0" prefWidth="92.0" text="Clear" />
               </children>
            </AnchorPane>
         </children>
      </AnchorPane>
   </children>
</VBox>
```

I tried using AnchorPane.bottomAnchor="0.0" AnchorPane.leftAnchor="0.0" AnchorPane.rightAnchor="0.0" AnchorPane.topAnchor="0.0" on my child AnchorPane but didn't work

Comment: Anchor pane is just not the correct approach here. Use a combination of (probably) Border Pane, Grid Panes, HBoxes and VBoxes. Any time you are using Anchor Pane and/or hard-coding sizes or layout positions, you are explicitly choosing not to make your layout responsive.

Comment: My guess is what you're seeing is the background of the VBox, and the Anchor Pane is not filling the VBox. But this is just the wrong approach to start with.

Comment: See if the ideas from https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46453780/javafx-how-i-can-bind-a-stage-with-screen-resolution/46455368#46455368 will help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I created a version of your `FXML` file. Try to incorporate the ideas from this answer into your Layout.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<!-- <?import com.gluonhq.charm.glisten.control.TextField?> -->

<?import javafx.geometry.Insets?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.Button?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.ComboBox?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.Label?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.TableColumn?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.TableView?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.TextField?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.HBox?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.StackPane?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.VBox?>
<?import javafx.scene.text.Font?>

<VBox alignment="CENTER" prefHeight="720.0" prefWidth="1080.0" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/18" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" fx:controller="com.maxxplusapi.controller.ActvityPlannerController">
   <children>
      <StackPane maxHeight="55.0" minHeight="43.0" style="-fx-background-color: #2e4b75;" />
      <VBox prefHeight="200.0" prefWidth="100.0" VBox.vgrow="ALWAYS">
         <children>
            <Label alignment="CENTER" maxWidth="1.7976931348623157E308" text="Aktivitätsplaner ">
               <font>
                  <Font size="36.0" />
               </font>
               <VBox.margin>
                  <Insets top="10.0" />
               </VBox.margin>
            </Label>
            <TextField fx:id="reminderDesc" promptText="Erinnerungsnachricht" style="-fx-border-color: black;">
               <VBox.margin>
                  <Insets left="300.0" right="300.0" top="15.0" />
               </VBox.margin>
            </TextField>
            <TextField fx:id="txtRemarks" prefHeight="26.0" prefWidth="388.0" promptText="Remarks" style="-fx-border-color: black;">
               <VBox.margin>
                  <Insets left="300.0" right="300.0" top="15.0" />
               </VBox.margin>
            </TextField>
            <HBox>
               <children>
                  <TextField fx:id="beginTime" prefHeight="26.0" prefWidth="172.0" promptText="Beginnzeit" style="-fx-border-color: black;" />
                  <Label alignment="CENTER_RIGHT" maxHeight="1.7976931348623157E308" maxWidth="1.7976931348623157E308" text="Intervall" HBox.hgrow="ALWAYS">
                     <HBox.margin>
                        <Insets right="5.0" />
                     </HBox.margin>
                  </Label>
                  <ComboBox fx:id="cycleComboBox" prefWidth="150.0" style="-fx-border-color: black;" />
               </children>
               <VBox.margin>
                  <Insets left="300.0" right="300.0" top="15.0" />
               </VBox.margin>
            </HBox>
            <Label maxWidth="1.7976931348623157E308" text="Projekt Bereich">
               <VBox.margin>
                  <Insets left="300.0" right="300.0" top="15.0" />
               </VBox.margin>
            </Label>
            <ComboBox fx:id="projectComboBox" maxWidth="1.7976931348623157E308" style="-fx-border-color: black;">
               <VBox.margin>
                  <Insets left="300.0" right="300.0" top="15.0" />
               </VBox.margin>
            </ComboBox>
            <HBox alignment="CENTER" maxWidth="1.7976931348623157E308" spacing="5.0">
               <children>
                  <Button fx:id="updateButton" mnemonicParsing="false" onMouseClicked="#Edit" prefHeight="25.0" prefWidth="92.0" text="Update" />
                  <Button contentDisplay="CENTER" mnemonicParsing="false" onMouseClicked="#DeleteData" prefHeight="25.0" prefWidth="92.0" text="Delete" />
                  <Button mnemonicParsing="false" onMouseClicked="#clearFields" prefHeight="25.0" prefWidth="92.0" text="Clear" />
               </children>
               <padding>
                  <Insets left="300.0" right="300.0" top="15.0" />
               </padding>
            </HBox>
            <TableView fx:id="tableViewBooking" maxHeight="1.7976931348623157E308" maxWidth="1.7976931348623157E308" onMouseClicked="#getSelected" VBox.vgrow="ALWAYS">
               <columns>
                  <TableColumn fx:id="tableID" editable="false" prefWidth="76.800048828125" text="id" />
                  <TableColumn fx:id="tableColName" editable="false" prefWidth="104.79997253417969" text="Erinnerung" />
                  <TableColumn fx:id="tableColRemarks" editable="false" prefWidth="104.79997253417969" text="Remarks" />
                  <TableColumn fx:id="tableColProject" editable="false" prefWidth="104.79997253417969" text="Projekt" />
                  <TableColumn fx:id="tableColDate" editable="false" prefWidth="83.20001220703125" text="Begin Datum" />
                  <TableColumn fx:id="tableColHours" editable="false" prefWidth="66.39996337890625" text="Stunde" />
                  <TableColumn fx:id="tableColType" editable="false" prefWidth="71.20001220703125" text="Intervall" />
                  <TableColumn fx:id="tableColSTime" editable="false" prefWidth="76.800048828125" text="Begin Zeit" />
                  <TableColumn fx:id="tableColETime" editable="false" prefWidth="76.800048828125" text="End Zeit" />
               </columns>
               <VBox.margin>
                  <Insets bottom="10.0" left="150.0" right="150.0" top="25.0" />
               </VBox.margin>
            </TableView>
         </children>
      </VBox>
   </children>
</VBox>
```

1. Save this as an `FXML` file to your machine.
2. Open it using SceneBuilder.
3. Press control+p after it opens in SceneBuilder.
4. Test by minimizing and maximizing the screen.

Comment: Merci! :) It works this way