# What can I do to achieve the same layout using panes

Tags: javafx

I am trying to display my nodes the same as the picture attached, but I am so bad with panes, so can someone help.

Am I using the wrong pane or what exactly?

And, how would it actually look like in code?

**goal layout**

[image]

**current layout**

[image]

I attached my code below and commented out the background image for you.

```
public class PD1 extends Application {

    GridPane root = new GridPane();
    private final String BUTTON_FONT = "Elephant";
    private final double BUTTON_FONT_SIZE = 15;
    private final String NEXT_FONT = "Elephant";
    private final double NEXT_SIZE = 18;

    private final String BORDER = "-fx-background-color:linear-gradient(#686868 0%, #232723 25%, #373837 75%, #757575 100%),,linear-gradient(#b9b9b9 0%, #c2c2c2 20%, #afafaf 80%, #c8c8c8 100%),linear-gradient(#f5f5f5 0%, #dbdbdb 50%, #cacaca 51%, #d7d7d7 100%);-fx-background-insets: 0,1,4,5;-fx-background-radius: 9,8,5,4;-fx-padding: 15 30 15 30";

    private final String SWSS_FONT = "Arial";
    private final double SWSS_SIZE = 18;
    private final String TX1_FONT = "Verdana";
    private double TX1_SIZE = 28;

    Button butNEXT = new Button("Next");
    Button butSWSS = new Button("Start with a saved schedule");
    Button butADD = new Button("Add");
    Button butREMOVE = new Button("Remove");
    BorderPane pane = new BorderPane();
    Label tx1 = new Label("Add Sections to Basket");
    Rectangle rec1 = new Rectangle();

    public void start(Stage primaryStage){
        Scene scene1 = new Scene(pane, 200, 200);
        primaryStage.setScene(scene1);
        primaryStage.setWidth(600);
        primaryStage.setHeight(600);
        primaryStage.setTitle("KFUPM schedule planner");
        primaryStage.show();

        layoutManager();
        applyStyle();
    }

    private void layoutManager(){
        HBox ADDandREMOVE = new HBox(35);
        ADDandREMOVE.getChildren().addAll(butADD, butREMOVE);

        HBox TopPane = new HBox(500);
        TopPane.getChildren().addAll(tx1,butSWSS)
        
        rec1.setWidth(1500);
        rec1.setHeight(850);
        rec1.setX(200);
        rec1.setY(100);
        rec1.setStroke(Color.BLACK);
        rec1.setFill(Color.TRANSPARENT);
        rec1.setStrokeWidth(11);

        pane.setPadding(new Insets(20, 20,20, 100));
        pane.setTop(TopPane);
        pane.setBottom(butNEXT);

        BorderPane.setAlignment(TopPane, Pos.CENTER);
        BorderPane.setAlignment(ADDandREMOVE, Pos.TOP_RIGHT);
        BorderPane.setAlignment(butNEXT, Pos.BOTTOM_RIGHT);
    }

    private void applyStyle() {
        butNEXT.setTextFill(Color.DARKGREEN);
        butADD.setTextFill(Color.DARKGREEN);
        butREMOVE.setTextFill(Color.DARKGREEN);
        butSWSS.setTextFill(Color.DARKGREEN);
        tx1.setTextFill(Color.DARKGREEN);


        butNEXT.setMinHeight(50);
        butNEXT.setMinWidth(100);
        butADD.setMinWidth(70);
        butADD.setMinHeight(35);
        butREMOVE.setMinWidth(70);
        butREMOVE.setMinHeight(35);
        butSWSS.setMinHeight(35);
        butSWSS.setMaxWidth(160);

        butADD.setFont(Font.font(BUTTON_FONT, FontWeight.BOLD, BUTTON_FONT_SIZE));
        butREMOVE.setFont(Font.font(BUTTON_FONT, FontWeight.BOLD, BUTTON_FONT_SIZE));
        butNEXT.setFont(Font.font(NEXT_FONT, FontWeight.BOLD, NEXT_SIZE));
        butSWSS.setFont(Font.font(SWSS_FONT, FontWeight.BOLD, SWSS_SIZE));

        butNEXT.setStyle(BORDER);
        butADD.setStyle(BORDER);
        butREMOVE.setStyle(BORDER);

        butSWSS.setWrapText(true);

        tx1.setFont(Font.font(TX1_FONT, FontWeight.BOLD, TX1_SIZE));

        pane.getChildren().add(rec1);
        rec1.setWidth(1500);
        rec1.setHeight(850);
        rec1.setX(200);
        rec1.setY(100);
        rec1.setStroke(Color.BLACK);
        rec1.setFill(Color.TRANSPARENT);
        rec1.setStrokeWidth(11);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args){
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

Comment: Just off the top of my head, I would try a `BorderPane` for the overall layout. Put the “Next” button in a right-aligned `HBox` in the bottom. I’m not sure what the actual requirements are for the top part, but if the idea is to have the “add sections to basket” centered in the whole layout and the “saved schedule” right-aligned you might need a stack pane containing two different panes to manage those layouts. Probably another `BorderPane` in the Center, with the two buttons in a right-aligned `HBox` in the top of that `BorderPane`.

Comment: Or maybe easier for the top part is an AnchorPane containing the label and the button. Anchor the label to both the left and right edges, and set its alignment to Center. Anchor the button only to the right edge.

Comment: This [`LayoutDemo`](https://github.com/openjdk/jfx/tree/master/apps/toys/LayoutDemo) is a convenient way to explore.

Comment: Using [Scene Builder](https://gluonhq.com/products/scene-builder/) (and its preview feature) is also an easy way to learn about layouts, even if you never end up using the resultant fxml.

Comment: Everything is straightforward except that middle section. That may need more explanation. I would suggest you use `SceneBuilder` for static `GUIs`. If you can't, one thing I do is use `SceneBuilder` and translate that to code.

Comment: See if the ideas from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74366028/how-to-make-anchorpane-size-responsive-to-the-maximized-screen-view/74367570#74367570) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46453780/javafx-how-i-can-bind-a-stage-with-screen-resolution/46455368#46455368) can help.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a basic layout which emulates your wireframe.

[image: sections]

The insets of some elements are a little different from the wireframe, but I liked it like this, so I kept it.  It is easy to change insets to something else though if preferred.

The layout was created using [SceneBuilder](https://gluonhq.com/products/scene-builder/), which I recommend for this kind of layout work.

- The "Show sample data" feature of Scene Builder was used to populate
  the view with sample data.
- The "Preview" feature of Scene Builder
  was used to verify the layout operation under different sizes.

**For layout:**

Layout uses the suggestions of James from comments, with a couple of differences (the center panel is a `VBox` containing a `ButtonBar` and `ListView`).

> I would try a `BorderPane` for the overall layout. Put the “Next” button in a right-aligned `HBox` in the bottom. I’m not sure what the actual requirements are for the top part, but if the idea is to have the “add sections to basket” centered in the whole layout and the “saved schedule” right-aligned you might need a stack pane containing two different panes to manage those layouts. Probably another `BorderPane` in the Center, with the two buttons in a right-aligned `HBox` in the top of that `BorderPane`.
>
> Or maybe easier for the top part is an `AnchorPane` containing the label and the button. Anchor the label to both the left and right edges, and set its alignment to Center. Anchor the button only to the right edge.

The top section in my layout uses a `StackPane` rather than an `AnchorPane`, but, as noted, perhaps an `AnchorPane` may be better in this case.  This is one of the few cases I have seen where `AnchorPane` may be preferrable.  It is really easy to misuse `AnchorPane` to perform absolute positioning of elements, which destroys resizability of the UI, so be careful with it.

**For sizing:**

- When you add layouts and some elements, Scene Builder will provide a default preferred height and width, which allows you to see an empty layout. But, for a real application, you almost never want the scene builder defaulted sizes.
- I reset the Scene Builder provided sizes to the `USE_COMPUTED_SIZE`, which is the default in FXML, which means when you generate the FXML from Scene Builder, there are *very few hardcoded sizes in the FXML, which is what you want*.
- Eliminating as many hardcoded sizes as possible and replacing them with `USE_COMPUTED_SIZE` is **very** important, otherwise your UI will not display properly as you resize the window.
- Also sizing hints such as `VGrow` settings are provided where needed.

For this simple layout, all work was done in Scene Builder with no editing of the generated FXML, sometimes you might need to manually modify the generated FXML, but generally not.

**For styling:**

The example uses minimum styling.  Styling should, in general, not be done in code or in FXML, but instead in a separate CSS style sheet which is attached to the FXML either in the FXML itself or in code.  Then associated style classes are attached to elements to style them.  The scene builder tool provides both the ability to attach a default style sheet to the FXML and to preview the FXML with different style sheets attached for different themes.

**Wiring a controller**

The example is just for layout demo purposes, so it does not provide the attributes in the FXML to wire the FXML to a controller.  Those would be things like:

- setting the controller class for the root layout.
- providing the `fx:id` values for the elements that need to be accessed from code.
- (optionally) specifying event handlers for elements (such as action handlers for buttons).

**Sample FXML**

You can load this FXML into Scene Builder to view or edit it.  Or load the FXML into a JavaFX application using the `FXMLLoader` to use it.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import javafx.geometry.Insets?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.Button?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.ButtonBar?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.Label?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.ListView?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.BorderPane?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.HBox?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.StackPane?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.VBox?>


<BorderPane maxHeight="-Infinity" maxWidth="-Infinity" minWidth="400.0" prefHeight="400.0" prefWidth="600.0" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/18" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1">
   <top>
      <StackPane BorderPane.alignment="CENTER">
         <children>
            <Button mnemonicParsing="false" prefWidth="100.0" text="Start with a Saved Schedule" textAlignment="CENTER" wrapText="true" StackPane.alignment="CENTER_RIGHT" />
            <Label text="Add Sections to Basket" />
         </children>
         <padding>
            <Insets bottom="10.0" left="10.0" right="10.0" />
         </padding>
      </StackPane>
   </top>
   <center>
      <VBox style="-fx-border-color: black; -fx-border-width: 3;" BorderPane.alignment="CENTER">
         <opaqueInsets>
            <Insets />
         </opaqueInsets>
         <children>
            <ButtonBar minHeight="-Infinity">
              <buttons>
                  <Button mnemonicParsing="false" text="Add" />
                <Button mnemonicParsing="false" text="Remove" />
              </buttons>
               <VBox.margin>
                  <Insets bottom="10.0" left="10.0" right="10.0" top="10.0" />
               </VBox.margin>
            </ButtonBar>
            <ListView VBox.vgrow="ALWAYS" />
         </children>
      </VBox>
   </center>
   <bottom>
      <HBox alignment="CENTER_RIGHT" BorderPane.alignment="CENTER">
         <children>
            <Button mnemonicParsing="false" text="Next" />
         </children>
         <padding>
            <Insets left="10.0" right="10.0" top="10.0" />
         </padding>
      </HBox>
   </bottom>
   <padding>
      <Insets bottom="10.0" left="10.0" right="10.0" top="10.0" />
   </padding>
</BorderPane>
```