# How to create responsive desktop applications UI in JavaFx?

Tags: java, javafx, responsive-design, fxml

The problem is that i want to know how to make responsive Desktop applications in JavaFx or Java Swing (preferred in JavaFx) . When i try to resize my application frame it's components size does not grow or shrink and similar is the situation when i try to run this on different screen sizes with different screen resolutions. I have searched on this topic but could not find any solution to this. So, any reference material will also be very helpful.

I just want to know how can i add responsiveness in my desktop applications.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import de.jensd.fx.glyphs.fontawesome.FontAwesomeIcon?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.Button?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.Label?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.PasswordField?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.TextField?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.AnchorPane?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.StackPane?>
<?import javafx.scene.text.Font?>

<StackPane maxHeight="-Infinity" maxWidth="-Infinity" minHeight="-Infinity" minWidth="-Infinity" prefHeight="500.0" prefWidth="700.0" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/20.0.1" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1">
    <AnchorPane prefHeight="500.0" prefWidth="700.0">
        <AnchorPane layoutY="1.0" prefHeight="500.0" prefWidth="250.0" styleClass="left-form" stylesheets="@../../stylesheets/loginDesign.css">
            <FontAwesomeIcon fill="WHITE" glyphName="STETHOSCOPE" layoutX="68.0" layoutY="228.0" size="12em" tabSize="0" />
            <Label layoutX="11.0" layoutY="274.0" text="Pesticide Management System" textFill="WHITE">
                <font>
                    <Font name="Berlin Sans FB" size="18.0" />
                </font>
            </Label>
        </AnchorPane>
        <AnchorPane layoutX="250.0" layoutY="1.0" prefHeight="500.0" prefWidth="450.0" styleClass="right-form" stylesheets="@../../stylesheets/loginDesign.css">
            <Label layoutX="133.0" layoutY="148.0" text="Welcome, Admin!" textFill="#374151">
                <font>
                    <Font name="Berlin Sans FB" size="25.0" />
                </font>
            </Label>
            <TextField layoutX="114.0" layoutY="226.0" prefHeight="30.0" prefWidth="220.0" promptText="Username" styleClass="text-field" stylesheets="@../../stylesheets/loginDesign.css" />
            <PasswordField layoutX="115.0" layoutY="273.0" prefHeight="30.0" prefWidth="220.0" promptText="Password" styleClass="text-field" stylesheets="@../../stylesheets/loginDesign.css" />
            <Button layoutX="115.0" layoutY="334.0" mnemonicParsing="false" prefHeight="35.0" prefWidth="220.0" styleClass="login-button" stylesheets="@../../stylesheets/loginDesign.css" text="Login" />
            <FontAwesomeIcon fill="#14b8a6" glyphName="USER_MD" layoutX="191.0" layoutY="128.0" size="7em" />
         <Button layoutX="401.0" mnemonicParsing="false" prefHeight="22.0" prefWidth="50.0" styleClass="close" stylesheets="@../../stylesheets/loginDesign.css">
            <graphic>
               <FontAwesomeIcon glyphName="CLOSE" size="15" />
            </graphic>
         </Button>
        </AnchorPane>
    </AnchorPane>
</StackPane>
```

and here is my css file

```
.left-form {
    -fx-background-color: #14b8a6;
    -fx-border-color: #000;
    -fx-border-width: 0.4px 0px .4px .4px;
}

.right-form {
    -fx-background-color: #fff;
    -fx-border-color: #000;
    -fx-border-width: .4px .4px .4px 0px;
}

.close {
    -fx-background-color: transparent;
    -fx-cursor: hand;
}

.close:hover {
    -fx-background-color: #ef4444;
}

.text-field {
    -fx-border-color: #3e3d3d;
    -fx-border-width: 0.5px;
    -fx-border-radius: 4px;
    -fx-font-family: "Tahoma";
    -fx-font-size: 13px; /* Add 'px' unit to font size */
}

.text-field:focused {
    -fx-border-color: #14b8a6;
    -fx-border-radius: 4px;
    -fx-border-width: 1.5px;
}

.login-button {
    -fx-background-color: #14b8a6;
    -fx-background-radius: 15px;
    -fx-cursor: hand;
    -fx-font-size: 14px; /* Add 'px' unit to font size */
    -fx-text-fill: #fff;
    -fx-font-family: "SansSerif";
}
```

Comment: [Java FX layout panes](https://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/layout/builtin_layouts.htm) are by default responsive. If your application is not resizing the way you want, it is because you are explicitly coding it not to.

Comment: [*Interview: Auto-responsive Layout in JavaFX (with Jakob Jenkov)*](https://m.youtube.com/watch?v=2BEinC7sJL4)

Comment: I’m sorry to see your clear and valid Question suffered unjustified down-votes. This happens all too often nowadays. Stack Overflow has lost its way, sadly.

Comment: @BasilBourque I disagree. If the OP's application is not acting in a responsive manner, it's because the code is explicitly written so that the UI is not responsive. Without seeing the code that is doing that, I see no way the question can be answered. Thus the question needs more details. If you think the question is answerable, why not answer it?

Comment: @james_D i said i want to know how can i implement responsive UI. If you think you can answer this question so i am providing you a FXML code that i generated from Scene Builder by using Layouts.

Comment: As I said, use the appropriate layout panes. Which ones to use and how to configure them depend on specifically how you want the application to respond. See the link above. I can't provide an answer because the question you posted is too vague and lacks details.

Comment: @james

https://drive.google.com/file/d/1-OktC1-IZm0WJD7eKiwwJbv_7pKQ0mfn/view?usp=sharing

Comment: Don't post links to code. Post the code in the question itself.

Comment: You are using layout panes that are specifically *not* responsive (`StackPane` and `AnchorPane`s) and hard coding the size and position of everything (by setting `layoutX`, `layoutY`, `prefWidth` and `prefHeight` to fixed values). So of course it is not responsive. Get rid of all the hard-coded values and replace the panes with ones that respond the way you want (which you haven't specified).

Comment: i got your point but if do not set the width and sizes of a component it looks so small on screen and ugly. how can i prevent that

Comment: @james_D I am just new to javafx don't know much about it.

Comment: Here are some starting ideas. I would recommend learning how the `Parent` nodes work. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46453780/javafx-how-i-can-bind-a-stage-with-screen-resolution/46455368#46455368

Comment: *"if do not set the width and sizes of a component it looks so small on screen and ugly"*. This now sounds like an x-y problem. It sounds like you started with a sizing/spacing/something else issue and made the UI non-responsive in an attempt to solve that problem. And now you're asking how to make it responsive. Start with a responsive UI (it looks like maybe you want two `VBox` inside an `HBox`?) and then if you can't make it look the way you want, ask *that* question.

Comment: While trying to _focus_ your very broad question, this  [tutorial](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/layout-tutorial/index.html) and this [`LayoutDemo`](https://github.com/openjdk/jfx/tree/master/apps/toys/LayoutDemo) are convenient ways to explore.

Comment: Offtopic, but I don't think that FontAwesomeFX is a very well-maintained project (the last update to the project was around five years ago).  You may wish to use [Ikonli instead](https://kordamp.org/ikonli/#_javafx).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To manage layouts, you need to be familiar with JavaFX's built-in layout panes.

- Oracle provide a [tutorial](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/layout-tutorial/builtin_layouts.htm), which is quite old, so the code style is out of date, but the underlying technology has not changed.
- [FXDocs from the OpenJFX documentation project](https://fxdocs.github.io/docs/html5/#_layout) also provide a layout tutorial.
- It's also worth reading the [API documentation for the layout package](https://openjfx.io/javadoc/20/javafx.graphics/javafx/scene/layout/package-summary.html) to see how the overall system works, and the API docs for each of the `Pane` subclasses.

There really is no shortcut to just experimenting with these layout panes and becoming familiar with how each of them manages layout and what properties they have.

If you want the layout to be *responsive* (i.e. for components to move and resize according to how much space is available) you need to:

1. Avoid hardcoding positions and sizes. This means you must not set `layoutX`, `layoutY`, `prefWidth`, `prefHeight` etc. Sometimes it *may* be helpful to set min/max sizes, but this can constrain the ability of the layout pane to respond to changes in available space.
2. Use layout panes that perform responsive layout. This means you generally should *not* use `StackPane` or `AnchorPane` except for very small, specific parts of the UI. By contrast, `BorderPane`, `HBox`, `VBox`, `GridPane`, `TilePane`, `FlowPane`, etc. provide the most responsiveness. Focus on *logical* layout rather than specific positioning.
3. Decide *how* you want the layout to respond. If there is extra space, how should it be used? If space is limited, what should shrink? This will determine which layout panes you decide to use.

Here is an approximation to the layout you defined using responsive panes. I also added `-fx-padding: 10;` to the `left-form` and `right-form` style classes in the CSS.

I could not get the FontAwesome parts to work, so I commented those out and made guesses as to how they should be. (In the version I found, `FontAwesomeIcon` is not a `Node` subclass. Not sure what is going on there.)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import de.jensd.fx.glyphs.fontawesome.FontAwesomeIcon?>

<?import javafx.geometry.Insets?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.text.Font?>
<BorderPane stylesheets="@loginDesign.css" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/20.0.1" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1">
    <left>
        <VBox alignment="CENTER" styleClass="left-form">
            <!--
            <FontAwesomeIcon fill="WHITE" glyphName="STETHOSCOPE" size="12em" tabSize="0" />
            -->
            <Label text="Pesticide Management System" textFill="WHITE">
                <font>
                    <Font name="Berlin Sans FB" size="18.0" />
                </font>
            </Label>
        </VBox>
    </left>
    <center>
        <BorderPane styleClass="right-form">
            <top>
                <HBox alignment="TOP_RIGHT">
                    <padding><Insets topRightBottomLeft="10"/></padding>
                    <Button mnemonicParsing="false" styleClass="close" text="X">
                        <!--
                        <graphic>
                            <FontAwesomeIcon glyphName="CLOSE" size="15" />
                        </graphic>
                        -->
                    </Button>
                </HBox>

            </top>
            <center>
                <VBox alignment="CENTER" spacing="20" fillWidth="true">
                    <Label text="Welcome, Admin!" textFill="#374151">
                        <font>
                            <Font name="Berlin Sans FB" size="25.0" />
                        </font>
                    </Label>
                    <TextField promptText="Username" styleClass="text-field" maxWidth="Infinity"/>
                    <PasswordField maxWidth="Infinity" promptText="Password" styleClass="text-field"  />
                    <Button maxWidth="Infinity" styleClass="login-button" text="Login" />
                    <!--
                    <FontAwesomeIcon fill="#14b8a6" glyphName="USER_MD" size="7em" />
                    -->
                </VBox>
            </center>
        </BorderPane>
    </center>
</BorderPane>
```

This produces

[image]

If I resize the screen, it responds reasonably well. You can tweak the code to make it respond differently, depending on your actual requirements.

[image]